# ios - Convert CGPoints (CIRectangleFeature) from Image to ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cgpoint

I am creating an iPhone app that detects Rectangle and captures image using **Camera**. I create an **overlay** over the biggest rectangle detected and once captured i have 4 `CGPoints` using `CIRectangleFeature` and an Image.

All 4 points in `CIRectangleFeature` are in landscape and my app is in Portrait.

When i display image in `UIImageView` on next controller the  the coordinates they are disturbed. The Image View is in **AspectFit Mode**. I searched and found a few of solutions, one was

```
extension CGPoint {
func scalePointByCeficient(ƒ_x: CGFloat, ƒ_y: CGFloat, viewWidth: CGSize, imageWidth: CGSize) -> CGPoint {
    let scale: CGFloat;
    scale = min(ƒ_x, ƒ_y)

    var p: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.x, y: self.y)

    p.x *= scale
    p.y *= scale

    p.x += (viewWidth.width - imageWidth.width * scale) / 2.0
    p.y += (viewWidth.height - imageWidth.height * scale) / 2.0

    return p

}

func reversePointCoordinates() -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: self.y, y: self.x)
}

func sumPointCoordinates(add: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: self.x + add.x, y: self.y + add.y)
}

func substractPointCoordinates(sub: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: self.x - sub.x, y: self.y - sub.y)
}}

class ObyRectangleFeature : NSObject {

public var topLeft: CGPoint
public var topRight: CGPoint
public var bottomLeft: CGPoint
public var bottomRight: CGPoint

var myRect: CIRectangleFeature?

public var viewWidth: CGSize
public var imageWidth: CGSize

var centerPoint_OLD : CGPoint{
    get {

        myRect?.topLeft = self.topLeft
        myRect?.topRight = self.topRight
        myRect?.bottomLeft = self.bottomLeft
        myRect?.bottomRight = self.bottomRight

        let superCenter: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: (myRect?.bounds().midX)!, y: (myRect?.bounds().midY)!)

        return superCenter
    }

}
var centerPoint : CGPoint{
    get {
        myRect?.topLeft = self.topLeft
        myRect?.topRight = self.topRight
        myRect?.bottomLeft = self.bottomLeft
        myRect?.bottomRight = self.bottomRight

        let superCenter: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: (myRect?.bounds().midX)!, y: (myRect?.bounds().midY)!)

        return superCenter
    }

}

convenience init(rectObj rectangleFeature: CIRectangleFeature) {
    self.init()

    myRect = rectangleFeature

    topLeft = rectangleFeature.topLeft
    topRight = rectangleFeature.topRight
    bottomLeft = rectangleFeature.bottomLeft
    bottomRight = rectangleFeature.bottomRight
}

override init() {

    self.topLeft = CGPoint.zero
    self.topRight = CGPoint.zero
    self.bottomLeft = CGPoint.zero
    self.bottomRight = CGPoint.zero

    self.viewWidth = CGSize.zero
    self.imageWidth = CGSize.zero

    super.init()


}


public func rotate90Degree() -> Void {

    let centerPoint =  self.centerPoint

    //        /rotate cos(90)=0, sin(90)=1
    topLeft = CGPoint(x: centerPoint.x + (topLeft.y - centerPoint.y), y: centerPoint.y + (topLeft.x - centerPoint.x))
    topRight = CGPoint(x: centerPoint.x + (topRight.y - centerPoint.y), y: centerPoint.y + (topRight.x - centerPoint.x))
    bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: centerPoint.x + (bottomLeft.y - centerPoint.y), y: centerPoint.y + (bottomLeft.x - centerPoint.x))
    bottomRight = CGPoint(x: centerPoint.x + (bottomRight.y - centerPoint.y), y: centerPoint.y + (bottomRight.x - centerPoint.x))

    print(self.centerPoint)
}

public func  scaleRectWithCoeficient(ƒ_x: CGFloat, ƒ_y: CGFloat) -> Void {
    topLeft =  topLeft.scalePointByCeficient(ƒ_x: ƒ_x, ƒ_y: ƒ_y, viewWidth: self.viewWidth, imageWidth: self.imageWidth)
    topRight = topRight.scalePointByCeficient(ƒ_x: ƒ_x, ƒ_y: ƒ_y, viewWidth: self.viewWidth, imageWidth: self.imageWidth)
    bottomLeft = bottomLeft.scalePointByCeficient(ƒ_x: ƒ_x, ƒ_y: ƒ_y, viewWidth: self.viewWidth, imageWidth: self.imageWidth)
    bottomRight = bottomRight.scalePointByCeficient(ƒ_x: ƒ_x, ƒ_y: ƒ_y, viewWidth: self.viewWidth, imageWidth: self.imageWidth)
}

public func correctOriginPoints() -> Void {

    let deltaCenter = self.centerPoint.reversePointCoordinates().substractPointCoordinates(sub: self.centerPoint)

    let TL = topLeft
    let TR = topRight
    let BL = bottomLeft
    let BR = bottomRight

    topLeft = BL.sumPointCoordinates(add: deltaCenter)
    topRight = TL.sumPointCoordinates(add: deltaCenter)
    bottomLeft = BR.sumPointCoordinates(add: deltaCenter)
    bottomRight = TR.sumPointCoordinates(add: deltaCenter)

    print(self.centerPoint)
}}
```

Its calling is like

```
ObyRectangleFeature *scaledRect = [[ObyRectangleFeature alloc] initWithRectObj:(id)rect_rect];

    float f_x = _sourceImageView.frame.size.width / _sourceImageView.image.size.width;
    float f_y = _sourceImageView.frame.size.height / _sourceImageView.image.size.height;

    [scaledRect setViewWidth:_sourceImageView.bounds.size];
    [scaledRect setImageWidth:_sourceImageView.image.size];

    [scaledRect scaleRectWithCoeficientWithƒ_x:f_y ƒ_y:f_x];
    [scaledRect rotate90Degree];
    [scaledRect correctOriginPoints];
```

Basically it checks scale factor and convert points to `UIImageView` coordinates and then considering Landscape factor it rotates it by 90 degree or more according to requirement. But the result i get is a bit problemetic

[image]

As you can see the rect that is made is displaced below the card. Any Ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for? Converting coordinates from image to UIImageView showing that image? Something like "func getViewCoordinates(forPointInImage point: CGPoint, convertedTo imageView: UIImageView) -> CGPoint" ? Or is it the other way around? Anyway what you posted there looks way too chaotic to fix.

Comment: Yes i am detecting the card and trying to convert the coordinates from Image To imageView. I am getting the converted point just alright. But issue is with orientation change they are messed up. U can see in the image coordinates are not on right position and while capturing they are right over the Card

Comment: You lost me here. You are saying that you are "getting the converted point just alright" but "not on right position". Explain exactly what goes on. Also where on the screenshot is the image view, which part is incorrect and also what is the image view content mode.

Comment: The points from camera controller are in landscape even when i capture using Portrait Mode. Now when in next controller i set the image to UIImageView (AspectFitMode) and try to draw overlay on the detected rectangle points (Card space) they are in wrong position. Then i try to rotate and change their respective position then i get the above result. The frame should be from top of card up to yellow base of card. I get rectangle in right position while capturing

Comment: @MaticOblak the ImageView is from top to above bottom bar that is white in color. Having Discard undo buttons. White color is merging with website white color

Comment: it is because you have set the uiimageview content mode to aspect fill. The image you are seeing is center cropped and the coordinates of actual image will vary. try using aspectfit and check the code. I believe it should work then.

Comment: @Swati it is alreadu on AspectFit Mode

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the contentMode of the UIImageView changes where the Image is placed in the view.  It appears that you are using aspect fit, so you have to calculate how much of the UImageView is the black bars and then divide the image size by the imageView size and then add the offset based on the black bars.  It is really not that hard, but the math can be tricky.  I would recommend using https://github.com/nubbel/UIImageView-GeometryConversion which does the math for all the different content modes.

Comment: I am already using the same code. I did took the concept from the link you mentioned and implemented it in my solution